# Join Tables to fetch user activity

Tags: mysql

I have three tables `users`, `users_followers` and `user_activity`.

`users` have all data about a user, email, username, password etch

`user_followers` have who is following who

and `user_activity` stores all activity of a user, ex. "wrote a post"

Im having a hard time to figure out how to join tables so the output will be that i have all activity for a user that I'm following.

So lets say that Adam follows Steve and Curt. Steve make a post and a few minutes Curt uploads a image, that Steve comments.

I would like to fetch that from the db in sorted by timestamp.

ex 
`Steve commented on a picture
Curt uploaded a image
steve made a post`

I have a sql fiddle here 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/59adf/4

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
select
u1.user_name as `user_name being followed`,
u2.user_name as `follower_name that followes`,
ua.*
from  users u1
join users_followers uf on uf.user_id=u1.user_id
join users u2 on u2.user_id = uf.follower_id
join user_activity ua on ua.user_id = u2.user_id
where u1.user_name='demo'
order by ua.activity_timestamp
```

Comment: Thanks @Jim ! But another, follow up question. Having some problems adding the between clause in the query. Added column `follower_since_timestamp`. to `users_followers`. Trying to figure out how this line should look like `AND  WHERE follower_since_timestamp BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(follower_since_timestamp) AND NOW()`

Comment: It seems that i was to fast to accept your answer. It seems that your query fetches from the activity table, but for that user specified in the where clause. it should fetch the activity of other users, that the user is following, corresponding from users_followers. so `where u1.user_name = 'demo'` should fetch the activity from who the user follows ex: steve, angela, mark etc. And present there activity from the activity table. Thanks again!